# Unicorn start up issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, unicorn

I cant figure out whats wrong with Unicorn, it doesnt want to start up. Any help is appreciated

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-195:~/www/tf/current$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn_rails (/home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn_rails)
Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - tmp/pids
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:254:in `mkdir'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:254:in `fu_mkdir'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `reverse_each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block in mkdir_p'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:202:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:80:in `reload'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:65:in `initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `new'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `initialize'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn_rails:22:in `load'
  /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/unicorn_rails:22:in `<top (required)>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

Comment: Did you try to clean up `tmp/pids`? Also I believe thats has something to do with file permissions

Comment: /tmp/pids doesnt even exist! ls: cannot access '/tmp/pids': No such file or directory

Comment: Check permissions for `/tmp` dir. Maybe unicorn cant create this file there

Comment: yeah I already thought of that, /tmp is 777

Comment: please show output of `ls -l /home/ubuntu/www/tf/current/tmp/pids` and `ls -ld /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/pids`

Comment: both dirs do not exist, pid file set to 
pid "/tmp/unicorn.project.pid"

Comment: Please show exact output, the first one is supposed to be a a symbolic link to the second. And show your `unicorn` configuration.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-17:~$ ls -l /home/ubuntu/www/tf/current/tmp/pids
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 31 Apr 27 13:06 /home/ubuntu/www/tf/current/tmp/pids -> /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/pids
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-17:~$ ls -ld /home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/pids
ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/www/tf/shared/pids': No such file or directory

Comment: config file is here https://pastebin.com/52tKXgNv

Answer (score 1):

You have symbolic link `~www/tf/current/tmp/pids` present but its target directory `~www/tf/shared/pids/` doesn't exist so the link is broken. `unicorn` is attempting to create `tmp/pids` directory in the `~www/tf/current/` but the symbolic link which already exists causes failure.

To fix this you need to create `~www/tf/shared/pids/` directory with appropriate ownership and permissions.